# 500 error in connect to quickbooks online

Tags: session, connect, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, reconnect

The normal flow of connecting to quickbooks works without any issues. Problem occurs when a user is in the following scenario:

1. User of our app is connected to one of the quickbooks company account by going through the authorize process and clicking on "Connect to quickbooks" button.
2. User signs out of his quickbooks company account.
3. User clicks on "Reconnect to QuickBooks" within bluDotMenu of quickbooks - a new popup opens which shows following message: 
   **The application does not exist or was deleted.**
4. Again User clicks on the "Connect to quickbooks" button, the quickbooks page shows 500 error with following message:

**500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.**

The url that displays above message is something like: https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/Begin?oauth_token=......................&oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Facme.com%3A8080%2FquickbooksIntegration%2FquickBookCallback

**NOTE: The same url when opened in another browser shows the quickbooks login page, which is the expected work flow.**

The problem looks like to be connected to some session used by quickbooks.

Answer (score 2):

I just got this error. I was logged in to QBO and clicked on "Apps". With Google Chrome I need to either:

- Clear all cookies related to the sites intuit *and* qbo.

OR

- Use an incognito window.